# Trying to use pymodbus as a slave but getting error

Tags: modbus

I have been successful using modbus-tk with an off the shelf modbus master simulator.  However, when the real master is wired in (an Automation Direct  PLC), the master does not get any response from the slave.

So I'm looking at using another modbus library (pymodbus). I try to run a very simple bit of code below but get the output as errors. I've checked serial port settings, use, etc..

Code:

```
client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='/dev/ttyS0', timeout=1,
                       baudrate=9600, stopbits=1, bytesize=8, parity='N')
client.connect()
log.debug("Reading Coils")
rr = client.read_coils(10001, 8, unit=UNIT)
log.debug(rr)
```

output:

> 2019-06-24 08:21:49,262 MainThread      DEBUG    PyModbusTest   :85       Reading Coils
>
> 2019-06-24 08:21:49,284 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :111      Current transaction state - IDLE
>
> 2019-06-24 08:21:49,295 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :116      Running transaction 1
>
> 2019-06-24 08:21:49,307 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :215      SEND: 0x2 0x1 0x27 0x11 0x0 0x8 0x67 0x4e
>
> 2019-06-24 08:21:49,318 MainThread      DEBUG    sync           :73       New Transaction state 'SENDING'
>
> 2019-06-24 08:21:49,331 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :224      Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
>
> 2019-06-24 08:21:50,344 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :234      Transaction failed. (Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received))
>
> 2019-06-24 08:21:50,382 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :235      Frame - [b''] not ready
>
> 2019-06-24 08:21:50,413 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :390      Getting transaction 2
>
> 2019-06-24 08:21:50,433 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :189      Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
>
> 2019-06-24 08:21:50,453 MainThread      DEBUG    PyModbusTest   :87       Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received)

Comment: Hello. I can't see from your code where you define the value of `UNIT`, this should be the modbus address of your PLC. Is it correct?

Comment: Sorry, I will try to format the code. UNIT is defined UNIT = 0x2

Comment: Right now I'm using Simply Modbus as the simulation master. It does not give me the ability to set the address but I will check. 2 is the slave address